# How to convert special symbol to emoji character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert special characters into emojis.

```js
let text = "This time also delivered a big product in an awesome package and fast delivery, and one more thing, this product manufactured on May 19, onlyðððð totally 5Â¶Â¶Â¶Â¶Â¶ starts, to this product but front is made up of some type of steel but it is not up to me, remaining is really good";
```

Comment: Do you know the encoding of the text?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a emoji to a text, you can directly add it in the string:

https://www.kirupa.com/html5/emoji.htm

On the other hand, if the text is a input and you wish to pickup the emoji, you can use this package :

https://github.com/iamcal/js-emoji

Answer (score 0):

*ES6/ES2015 introduced a way to represent Unicode points in the astral planes (any Unicode code point requiring more than 4 chars), by wrapping the code in graph parentheses:*

**Format:** `\u{XXXXX}`

**For Example:**

`\u{1F436}` will work and a dog emoji will appear

For reference you can check out [this link](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-unicode/).

Comment: I want to convert this Â¶Â¶Â¶Â¶Â¶  into any meaningful image or emoji.

Comment: these special characters are not in unicode. try to convert it into unicode and you will get a code like "1F436" in \u{1F436}